# Create map or objects from struct with additional properties as key

Tags: dictionary, go, struct, slice

i've struct which build like following

```
type RTB struct {
    ID            string
    Modules       []*Modules   
    Req            []*Req
}
```

Now inside module I've the following

```
type Modules struct {
    Name       string
    Type       string
    Path       string
    Id         string
}
```

Now I've the object of RTB in the memory and I want to create `map` (that I can loop on it si object which will be like following:

```
   NewObject {
        Type          string//the value from the module struct
        Modules       []*Modules // From the rtb struct  
    }
```

of course I can loop on it (if there is not more elegant way...) and create new struct (like the new object) and fill the data from both structs, but there is better way in Golang like map to store this data?

Comment: I think looping is what you are looking for

Comment: Can you make it clear?

Comment: @aerokite - I want to create object which is more sutible to work with that contain the type as key and the modules a values, how can I achieve it with golang

Comment: You have to use a loop to go over the modules and build a map from it. No easier way. If you need this functionality in multiple places, put it into a utility function and call that wherever needed.

Comment: @icza - thanks, it will be great if you can add example as answer and I close the question as answerd .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a loop to go over the modules and build a map from it. No easier way. If you need this functionality in multiple places, put it into a utility function and call that wherever needed.

Example building the map:

```
rtb := &RTB{
    Modules: []*Modules{
        {Name: "n1", Type: "t1"},
        {Name: "n2", Type: "t1"},
        {Name: "n3", Type: "t2"},
    },
}

m := map[string][]*Modules{}

for _, mod := range rtb.Modules {
    m[mod.Type] = append(m[mod.Type], mod)
}

// Verify result (JSON for "nice" outpout):
fmt.Println(json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(m))
```

Output:

```
{"t1":[{"Name":"n1","Type":"t1"},{"Name":"n2","Type":"t1"}],"t2":[{"Name":"n3","Type":"t2"}]}
<nil>
```

If you want a slice of `NewObject` instead of the map, you can build that like this:

```
// m is the map built above.

var newObjs []*NewObject
for k, v := range m {
    newObjs = append(newObjs, &NewObject{
        Type:    k,
        Modules: v,
    })
}

fmt.Println(json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(newObjs))
```

Output:

```
[{"Type":"t1","Modules":[{"Name":"n1","Type":"t1"},{"Name":"n2","Type":"t1"}]},{"Type":"t2","Modules":[{"Name":"n3","Type":"t2"}]}]
<nil>
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cYUHGI0XN5C).

Comment: Thanks a lot! 1+ , last question :) is it possible to create the map with the key as `object` with additional properties i.e.`"Type":"t1"` and `"Name": "myname"` will have additional property?

Comment: something like `m := map[string,string][]*Modules{}` i've tried it and I got error..any idea how I can use it ?

Comment: @JennyHilton That is possible. One way is to wrap the key properties in a struct, and use this struct type as the key type of the map. E.g. `type Key struct { Type, Name string }`, and then the map: `m := map[Key][]*Modules{}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @icza

Comment: Btw when changing it to Key as suggest I got error at : `m[mod.Type] = append(m[mod.Type], mod)` , how should I adopt it to work with key? thank you